# Неправильно загружается mp3 файл php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь сделать загрузку музыки на сервер, путём POST запроса.

Файл загружается, но при попытке его воспроизвести, музыка воспроизводится некорректно, а именно длится вместо 7 минут 20 секунд и идёт не с начала. Ошибка сохраняется, как я заметил, для файлов размеров > 8МБ, для файлов меньших размеров, всё работает.

Проблема не с плеером, поскольку загруженный файл просто испорчен (проверил аудио-плеером винды), при этом с исходным файлом всё в порядке. ini настройки вроде стоят по умолчанию, то есть размер файл меньше порога.

Собственно, php код:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $gUser)
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $artist = $_POST['artist'];
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO uploaded_music (author_uid, name, artist) VALUES ('$gUser[uid]', '$name', '$artist')");

    $id = 'music'.(mysqli_insert_id($link)).'.mp3';
    if ($result)
    {
        @copy($_FILES['music']['tmp_name'], $path.$id);
        header ('location: /view_music.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вы отдаёте мп3?

Comment: В каком смысле? Если я правильно вас понял, то я использую jsqplayer, конкретно файл передаю
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM uploaded_music WHERE 1 ORDER BY music_id DESC"))
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
     $id = $row['music_id'];
     $path = "uploaded_music/music".$id.".mp3";
     $artist = $row['artist'];
     $name = $row['name'];
     echo '{
      title: "'.$name.'",
      mp3: "'.$path.'",
     },
     ';
    }

Comment: сервер apache? или другой.

Comment: Если файл самому скачать по ссылке файл нормальный возвращает?

Comment: "Если файл самому скачать по ссылке файл нормальный возвращает?", нет файл испорченный

Comment: Сервер - apache.

Comment: поменяли  `copy` -> `move_uploaded_file` ? А так же использовать @ плохая идея.

Comment: Поменял, ничего не изменилось

Comment: После правки php.ini Apache перегрузили?

Comment: А вы весь код привели?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию размер пост запроса `post_max_size` 8мб ;)

Похоже что проблемы с выделенной памятью для PHP.

Вкратце (php.ini)

`memory_limit > post_max_size > upload_max_filesize`

**memory_limit** Достаточно что бы правильно читать мп3. Если файл 8мб памяти для пхп нужно гораздо больше!

**Так же**

1. `copy` -> `move_uploaded_file`
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php
2. http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Comment: Вот, что у меня стоит:

post_max_size = 32M
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 32M

Ошибка при этом сохраняется

Comment: *upload_max_filesize = 32М